# Why is there a difference between "diff" and "svn diff"?

Tags: svn

I have two files checked out with SVN with the same revision (2728).

```
$ svn update build.xml
At revision 2728.
$ svn update ../../java-skel/trunk/build.xml
At revision 2728.
```

When I try to find out the difference "svn diff" does not show any difference.

```
$ svn diff build.xml ../../java-skel/trunk/build.xml
```

But there are differences.

```
$ diff build.xml ../../java-skel/trunk/build.xml
67c67
<     <format property="build.timestamp" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"/>
---
>     <format property="now" pattern="yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss,SSSZ"/>
86a87
>       <exclude name="**/.ignore/**"/>
98c99
<         <attribute name="Build-Date" value="${build.timestamp}"/>
---
>         <attribute name="Build-Date" value="${now}"/>
110a112
>         <exclude name="**/.ignore/**"/>
```

Why is the difference not shown by SVN?

Comment: `svn diff` is for the _same_ file, comparing to revisions & working copy (usually BASE (the revision you last checked out) and WC (working copy, the file you now have in your disk)). It is not meant to diff _different_ files. What happens here is: if neither of your files have been changed since your last checkout, there is no difference (BASE && WC are equal). `svn diff ... multiple files....` essentially does a `diff file@WC file@BASE` for reach individual file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `svn diff` command isn't comparing the two files, it's asking Subversion to give you the changes in each of the two files, and as neither have changed since your last revision, the command doesn't give any output.

If you run `svn help diff` then you'll see six different ways in which the command is being used.  You're using #2, `diff [-c M | -r N[:M]] [TARGET[@REV]...]` with more than one target.  It seems like you're thinking you're using #4, #5 or #6, which can compare an arbitrary file *on the server* with a file on disk or on the server, but which won't compare two files on disk -- that's what the regular `diff` command is for.

You can coerce `svn diff` into comparing local files by using the `--old` and `--new` parameters explicitly:

```
svn diff --old=build.xml --new=../../java-skel/trunk/build.xml
```

Comment: My SVN client might be too old, because I get the error: `Sorry, svn_client_diff4 was called in a way that is not yet supported`. But thanks for the answer. Using the URLs for the local files seems to work.